# Add to cart goes 404 redirect in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, php-7, 404, magento2.3.x

> After clicking on add to cart of any product.

**It goes to 404 page. But when i cleared cache page its working fine and product added to card and cart page is totally working fine but after some day again and again i found this problem. Please help to figure out this.**